# How to symbolize / compile the following sympy code that throws ValueError: Can't determine orientation

Tags: python, sympy

I have this bit of code for calculating the internal angles of a polygon using sympy -

```py
pt1 = sympy.Point((0, 0))
pt2 = sympy.Point((1, 1))
pt3 = sympy.Point((0, 1))
pt4 = sympy.Point((1, 0))

poly = sympy.Polygon(pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4)

print(poly.angles[pt2])
```

```
5.49778714378214
```

---

How do I lambdify this code?

I get the following error when I replace the numeric values with symbols -

```py
pt1 = sympy.Point(*sympy.symbols("x0 y0"))
pt2 = sympy.Point(*sympy.symbols("x1 y1"))
pt3 = sympy.Point(*sympy.symbols("x2 y2"))
pt4 = sympy.Point(*sympy.symbols("x3 y3"))

poly = sympy.Polygon(pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4)
angles = poly.angles[pt2]

sympy.lambdify(
    sympy.symbols("x0 y0")
    + sympy.symbols("x1 y1")
    + sympy.symbols("x2 y2")
    + sympy.symbols("x3 y3"),
    angles,
)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dev/.virtualenvs/ddgai-b0692ca2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 564, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "/Users/dev/Projects/dara/ddgai/pages/Pad.py", line 111, in <module>
    angles = poly.angles[pt2]
  File "/Users/dev/.virtualenvs/ddgai-b0692ca2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/geometry/polygon.py", line 266, in angles
    cw = self._isright(args[-1], args[0], args[1])
  File "/Users/dev/.virtualenvs/ddgai-b0692ca2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/geometry/polygon.py", line 231, in _isright
    raise ValueError("Can't determine orientation")
ValueError: Can't determine orientation
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to achieve your goal with the current implementation, as `Polygon.angles` expects numerical coordinates for the vertices. The error is telling you that it can't compute the angles because it cannot determine the orientation of the symbolic vertices.

Comment: Alternative implementations are welcome!